# How to show the image name as the title of the window in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How to get the name of the image as the title of the window when using imshow in matlab.

Eg: I use the following code as to show the original image and the skeletonized image.

```
figure
subplot(1,2,1)
imshow(BW_Original)
subplot(1,2,2)
imshow(BW_Thinned)
```

I want to show the image name as the title of the window that pop ups. Can someone help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to change the [`'Name'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#property_d0e271850) of the figure to your image name, as well as setting the [`'NumberTitle'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#property_d0e271921) to `'off'` (to remove the "Figure #:" that appears):

```
set(gcf, 'Name', 'image_name', 'NumberTitle', 'off');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the name of the figure when calling `figure`

```
figure('name', 'BW comparison image name here')
subplot(1,2,1); imshow(BW_Original);
subplot(1,2,2); imshow(BW_Thinned);
```

Gnovice also mentions that you might want to remove the figure number from the name, this can be done when calling `figure` too:

```
figure('name', 'BW comparison image name here', 'numbertitle', 'off')
```